# PHP: Using POST on OOP and storing in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, post

Ok im kinda new to using oop on php, So this what im tryna do. getting the value of the textbox putting them in an array then storing them in database but the problem is it doesnt store the data

```
<?php
require ('employmentfunc.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$arr = array(isset ($_POST['company']), isset ($_POST['position']));

if (isset($_POST['ok']))
{
    $a = new empfunc();
    $a->SaveA($arr);
}
?>
<form name="emp" action="employmentform.php" method="POST">

<TD><input type="text" name="company">
<td><input type="text" name="position">
<input type="submit" class="button1" name="ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>



<?php
class empfunc{

function saveA($array){
    $sqlconnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","employment");
    $sqlquery = "INSERT INTO info(`Company`, `Position`) VALUES ('$array[0]', '$array[1]')";
    mysqli_query ($sqlconnect, $sqlquery);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Does it run without an error? You appear to have a typo in the method name(capitalized at the top, lowercase at the definition)

Comment: Run this `echo "INSERT INTO info(`Company`, `Position`) VALUES ('$array[0]', '$array[1]')";`

Comment: From where `$sqlconnect` comes?

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL Injection. [You should use prepared statements instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/479156).

Comment: @man0v runs but stores 1 in my database which is annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the way you are building the `$arr` variable. You are storing boolean results from the `isset` function calls instead of storing the data itself. I would rewrite that part of the code using a few more lines to make it more readable. Since you are storing the result of `isset` your values stored in the database will be either 0 or 1. Instead, either do not use the `isset` function or else change them to a ternary operator to store some default data if they are not set:

```
$arr = array(
    isset ($_POST['company']) ? $_POST['company'] : 'No Company', 
    isset ($_POST['position']) ? $_POST['position'] : 'No Position'
);
```

or if you just want to skip the `isset` validation:

```
$arr = array($_POST['company'], $_POST['position']);
```

Comment: Yes it worked but i have one more problem i have this radio button which simply should return yes or no but upon loading the form this things shows up:

Notice: Undefined index: military in C:\xampp\htdocs\func\employmentform.php on line 34


is there any fix fo this

Comment: ow i solved it thanks again man haha im used to do thing on c# php takes a whole different approach